# I want to place my business page linkedin feed onto our Drupal website. Is it possible?

Tags: 8, social-network

This question is most likely more about LinkedIn. I can't find answers to this question anywhere. It is as if no one ever asked it.

I have follow links to the linkedin business page. I have share links to the visiting user's linkedin feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at these links:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/get-linkedin-posts

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/get-linkedin-posts/how-to-setup-get-linkedin-posts-module

I haven't played with Linkedin or with this module, but that's what you need if I understand right.

It's up to you if you install it or not.

Comment: Great n thanks - I had tried a search for a module before D8 - I simply over looked trying that approach. Thanks for the wakeup call...